# NotaBene 10 under wine

Tags: 13.10, wine

I am trying to run NotaBene in Ubuntu under wine.

I think I managed to install it, but when I try to run it the screen changes to the wine screen and then after a few moments it disappears and I'm back in the Ubuntu desktop.

Under "Properties" I tried setting the permission but as I click the box and after about 1 sec the "click" tick disappears - I take it the software doesn't like the NotaBene exe file.

Any ideas of where I go from here, please?

Allan

linal.williams@metroweb.co.za

Answer (score 0):

Normally when there are issues with a program in WINE (especially one that is meant to be supported) the best thing to do is to install winetricks. This allows you to install things such as extra link libraries. I have never used NotaBene and there appears to be no info on which (if any) tricks it needs, just that it should work in WINE. I would suggest installing winetricks:

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

then running the following to install some common libraries:

```
winetricks msxml3 msxml4 wsh56 msscript comctl32 jscript
```

at some point the installer may stop and ask you to download some files it normally opens the website and the folder to download it to. After this you may need to re-run the command to do the install (I can't remember if it pauses or stops, the terminal is quite informative if you read the output).